# $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I've been working on proving the following for a homework problem:
Let $x \in \mathbb{ R } ^n$ and consider the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ vector norms defined by 
$$
 \| x \|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \ , \ \| x \|_2 = \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 \right ) ^{1/2} \ 
$$
Prove that 
$$
 \| x \|_1 \le \sqrt{n} \| x \|_2
$$
I can easily prove it in the specialized case $n=2$: we consider the square terms 
$$
 \left ( \| x \|_1 \right )^2  = (|x_1| + |x_2|)^2 = |x_1|^2 + 2 |x_1||x_2| + |x_2|^2
$$
and 
$$
 \left ( \sqrt{2} \| x \|_2 \right )^2 = 2 (|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2)
$$
Consider the difference, 
$$
 \left ( \sqrt{2} \| x \|_2 \right )^2 - \left ( \| x \|_1 \right )^2 = |x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 - 2|x_1||x_2| = \left ( |x_1| - |x_2| \right ) ^2 \ge 0
$$
Therefore, 
$$
 \left ( \sqrt{2} \| x \|_2 \right )^2 \ge \left ( \| x \|_1 \right )^2
$$
and the desired result follows.
I'm not sure if this idea generalizes.  I am fairly certain it will be more convenient to consider the squares as we did for $n=2$, but the algebraic ``trick'' does not seem to workout. In general, 
$$
 \left ( \| x \|_1 \right ) ^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 + 2 \cdot \sum_{i \ne j} |x_i||x_j|
$$
and 
$$
 \left (\sqrt{n} \| x \|_2 \right ) ^2 = n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2
$$
so that when we subtract, 
$$
 \left (\sqrt{n} \| x \|_2 \right ) ^2 - \left ( \| x \|_1 \right ) ^2 = (n-1) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 - 2 \sum_{i\ne j}|x_i||x_j|
$$
I don't see an obvious factorization to prove that this is positive.  Maybe you do, or maybe another approach is better for the general case.  Either way, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions you may have!

Comment: You have the right idea.  Have you tried using induction on n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i = 1}^n 1\cdot |x_i| \le \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n 1^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n |x_i|^2\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{n}\|x\|_2.$$